# What's the design pattern at the end of infinite scroll?

Tags: design-patterns, ios, e-commerce, infinite-scroll

I have an app (iOS) that outputs a grid with all the applicable products.

Is there a prevalent design pattern that indicates the end of infinite scroll?

Comment: if there's an end, it's not infinite... :)

Comment: In ecommerce, a common goal of the site is to get users to look at products, so if the user gets to the bottom of the list without diving into a product, it might be a good opportunity to guide them toward one of the site's other objectives...e.g. sign up for coupons in email, look at a different category of products, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, it's an important UX opportunity!

When the user scrolls to the end of a list, you want to:

1. **Communicate that the end has been reached**.  You don't want the user to wonder whether more items are loaded, or whether the page is still loading.
2. **Suggest the next step!!!**  This is an important opportunity! The user has just interacted with the list so **you know you have her attention**.  Moreover, you know it's likely that the user has finished looking at the list and is figuring out what to do next.  This combination of (a) a captive attention and (b) user decision point can create a great opportunity to provide a call to action, more information, or a suggestion for one or more next steps!

---

In the top left example, the end-of-scroll just presents some passive information.  The other 5 examples show how a UX designer might capitalize on the user's attention to create more interaction/stickiness:

[image]

The exact next step you suggest depends on your overall UX objectives, what behavior(s) you are trying to create for users, and what empirically is successful when you test (e.g. A/B testing a few different buttons may yield very surprising insight).

Comment: Love the next step suggestion, it's a great marketing technique as well to keep the user engaged with you, and get them to continue shopping, or sign up with the nice call-to-action.

Answer (score 1):

You could either simply display a line showing end of content. like below

[image: End of scroll!]

There is a very popular ecommerce app called Myntra in India which does a very interesting thing. They show a quote by a famous fashion designer at the end of content Screenshot is Android, but they do the same thing on iOS.

[image: Myntra's showing quote at the end of the list, Android]
There is no definite pattern. You could do a rebound scroll and use simple visual cues.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[   scroll  ]
[A]  [B]  [C]
```

***Let user come to a distinct end and select among several infinite scolls.

To really make it infinite one button should be called `Home` ;)***

Answer (score -1):

[image: Timehop end of the list image]

Show some graphic at the bottom maybe like Timehop app does. Think the reverse of 'pull down to refresh'.

Half of that dino in the picture is revealed only of you pull the list way higher up by extra force.